# How to convert this string "03:34:21" into seconds in Java

Tags: java, android

In my app I have a timer that updates a TextView each second, in the following format:

```
00:00:00 - hours, minutes, seconds.
```

In onPause I record in SharedPreferences the value of tvTimer as a String, for example 00:21:13 (21 minutes, 13 seconds) and the time when the onPause occurred

In onResume I obtain those values and try to add the time between now and previous onPause to the value of the tvTimer string, you can see that in the TODO, but I don't know how to do that.

```
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;

private void startTimer() {
    tvTimer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tvTimer.setText(obtainTimerProgress());

    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
}

private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;

        int hours = mins / 60;

        tvTimer.setText(String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", mins) + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        // TODO Find a suitable moment to customHandler.removeCallbacks
    }

};

private String obtainTimerProgress() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Constant.USER_PREFERENCES, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String timerProgress = preferences.getString(Constant.PROGRESS + getUserId(), "00:00:00");
    if (timerProgress != null && !timerProgress.contentEquals("") && !timerProgress.contentEquals("00:00:00")) {
        long timeOfTimerPause = preferences.getLong(Constant.TIME_OF_ON_PAUSE + getUserId(), 0);
        long now = new Date().getTime();
        long differenceBetweenThenAndNow = (now - timeOfTimerPause ) / 1000;
        // TODO Parse the string "00:43:34" and turn it into seconds, add differenceBetweenThenAndNow and format it as "00:53:22" again
    }
    return timerProgress;
}
```

In onPause I record in SharedPreferences the value of tvTimer as a String, for example 00:21:13 (21 minutes, 13 seconds) and the time when the onPause occurred

In onResume I obtain those values and try to add the time between now and previous onPause to the value of the tvTimer string, you can see that in the TODO, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Look up the javadoc for `String.split`.  Also `Integer.parseInt`.  Is that giving you any ideas?

Comment: BTW: it is simpler / cleaner / more efficient to use one `format` call instead of 3 calls + clunky string concatenation.

Comment: To build/parse date you can use SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String time = "1:02:59";
        String timeSplit[] = time.split(":");
        int seconds = Integer.parseInt(timeSplit[0]) * 60 * 60 +  Integer.parseInt(timeSplit[1]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(timeSplit[2]);
        System.out.println(seconds);
     }
}
```

Split the string using : and then fetch each value and convert into seconds. I have marked the lines in bold. Hope this was helpful